# why psudeo after element's width is not relative to its parents width?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to add a underline like symbol below the active link for that purpose i am used ::after element and set it's width to 100% to get its parent element's width but the psudo element is way much bigger when width is 100%;

my html code is

```
<header class="main-header">
  <a class="category-name">
    <span> Sneakers </span>
  </a>
  <nav class="main-nav">
    <ul class="main-nav-list">
      <li class="m">
        <a class="main-nav-link" href="#how">Collections</a>
      </li>
      <li><a class="main-nav-link" href="#meals">Men</a></li>
      <li>
        <a class="main-nav-link" href="#testimonials">Women</a>
      </li>
      <li><a class="main-nav-link" href="#pricing">About</a></li>
      <li><a class="main-nav-link nav-cta" href="#cta">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <ul class="my__ac-list">
    <li class="nav--cart_icon" id="cartBtn">
      <a href="#" class="cart-icon"
        ><img src="./images/icon-cart.svg" alt="cart icon" srcset=""
      /></a>
      <p class="cart--strip">3</p>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">
        <img
          class="profile-thumbnail"
          src="./images/image-avatar.png"
          alt="image-avatar"
          srcset=""
        />
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</header>
```

my css code is bit lengthier i couldnot format correctly so i have created code containg my html and css

codepen link = https://codepen.io/sinan-m/pen/abKQaxp

i want to add a underline below the active navigation link like in design

my design image https://github.com/front-end-mentor-works/e-com-product-page/blob/main/design/active-states-basket-filled.jpg

Comment: May also be useful: https://ctrlaltdelor.wordpress.com/2014/01/09/a-single-rule-for-apostrophes/

Comment: I think `%` is relative to containing element, not parent element.

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor then how to get it's parent's width, can i acheive the my goal with after element?

Comment: Try border colour.

Comment: to try border color also i have to get the li element's width

Comment: I am not sure if you can get it is parent width. But, you can use a border at the bottom. Or encapsulate the element. I am a bit out of practice. However I remember some of the new CSS dose fix some problems like this.

Comment: No, just give the `li` a border.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.main-nav-list li.m for this selector you need to add position: relative. Beacause right now the after pseudoelement is not positioned relative to the li element.

> position: absolute;

An element with position: absolute; is positioned relative to the nearest positioned ancestor (instead of positioned relative to the viewport, like fixed).

However; if an absolute positioned element has no positioned ancestors, it uses the document body, and moves along with page scrolling.

Because you didn't set position:relative on the li, he after element takes the width of the window browser. That's why when set to 100%, it's so wide.

Comment: you're welcome. the silliest mistakes are unfortunately often the hardest to spot yourself.

Answer (score 0):

## Result

[image]

## Solution

```
.main-nav-list li.m {
  border-bottom: 5px solid tomato;
}
```

I edited the rule for the `.main-nav-list li.m`  selector in the code pen.

To get it more spaced out, then add some padding. e.g.

```
.main-nav-list li.m {
  border-bottom: 5px solid tomato;
  padding-bottom: 1ex;
}
```

You also need to change

```
.main-nav-list {
  …
  align-items: top;
  …
}
```

To keep the alignment good. And remove the yellow.